# How I insert color in a border of EditText?

Tags: android, colors

I need to insert the color blue in a border of EditText in my project. How I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a xml file with the below code into the drawable folder as "edittextborder.xml"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FDEEF4" />
 <corners
      android:radius="15dp" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#2B65EC" /> 
 </shape>
```

where #2B65EC represents the border of the edittext color. "#2B65EC" - ocean blue

Also refer this one to the Edittext code as below one

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >
```